# Let $f:V\to \Bbb{R} $, such that $f\neq 0$. Prove that $f$ is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ such that $\dim V=n,\;n\geq 2$ and $$f:V\to \Bbb{R} $$ be linear such that $f\neq 0.$
I want to

1. prove that $f$ is surjective,
2. prove or disprove that $f$ is injective,
3. I also want to find $\dim \ker f.$

I think that it suffices to prove that $\operatorname{Im}f= \Bbb{R}.$ We have the following inclusion:

$$\operatorname{Im}f= \{f(x)\in\Bbb{R}:x\in V\}\subset \Bbb{R},$$ but I'm finding it hard to prove that $$\Bbb{R}\subset\operatorname{Im}f= \{f(x):x\in V\}.$$

For kernel, we have that

$\ker f= \{x\in V:f(x)=0\},$ but I am stuck at this point.

No.3 is not a problem, since $\dim V=\dim \ker f+ \dim \operatorname{Im}f.$  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: $V = \Bbb{R}^n $ and observe what happens in those case and then generalize

Answer (score 3):

For $1$, use the fact that $f(cx)=cf(x)$ for all $c\in\Bbb{R}$.

For $2$, use the fact that $f$ is injective if and only if $\dim\ker f=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is surjective: Since $f\neq 0$, there is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there is $v\in V: f(v)=x$. We have to find a preimage for an arbitrary $a\in \mathbb{R}$:
Just calculate $f(\frac{a}{x}\cdot v)$ by using linearity.

About injectiveness: A surjective linear map that is also injective is an isomorphism. Compare the dimensions of $\mathbb{R}$ and $V$.

Comment: additional you say more about dual map.

Comment: @Ninjahatori Excuse me, I don't really understand your comment. There is no use of dual maps in my answer. I guess that the TO is not familiar to the dual space, given his question. Do you really think that incorporating dual maps would improve the answer?